# Setting up TFS 2010 - Lab Mananger with SCVMM R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, team-foundation-server, scvmm

I am trying to use Lab Manager with System Center Virtual Machine Manager R2.

This is the error message I get when I try to Configure the SCVMM setting in TFS admin Console:

```
Team Foundation Services are not available from server MyTFS2010Server.
Technical information (for adminstrator):
  Method not found: 'Void
Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.ClientCache.set_UseWeakReferences(Boolean)'.
```

Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Am I going to have to uninstall SCVMM R2 and go back to R1?  Think [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=462380) make me think so.

If anyone knows a workaround to this I would love to hear it!  (If not I would also take advice on downgrading to SCVMM R1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grrrr, I wish I had known that this incompatibility existed.

I am uninstalling R2 and installing R1.

Comment: R1 cannot have hosts that are Windows Server 2008 R2.  That means if you use R1 then you have to go back to Windows Server 2008 (R1)